# How to insert the vales in database using modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons, **login** and **register**. If I click the login button the login modal should open and register button means the register modal should open.
What I'm trying to do is that after opening register modal I want to validate the form and insert the values into a database. But when I  click **register_submit** nothing is happening.

```js
<!-- Admin Extension -->
 <script src="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/javascripts/theme.admin.extension.js"></script>
 <script src="http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/edge/assets/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#register_submit').click(function(){
   alert();
    if($('#registerForm').valid()){
     
    /*$.ajax({
    url:'register_bussiness.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: $('form#registerForm').serialize(),
    success:function(data){
     //var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
     console.log(data);
     if(data == "Success"){
     $('#btn-submit').prop('disabled', true);
     $("#bussiness_suc_alert").show();
     $("#bussiness_suc_alert").fadeOut(2000);
     }
    },
    });*/
    return false;
    }
   });
  });
  </script>
```

```html
<li><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</button></li>
      <li style="margin-left: 10px;"><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button></li>


<div class="container">
       <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 9999;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" style="padding:5px 50px;">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4>Login</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
         <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usrname">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="psw"> Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
        </div><br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Login </button>
         </form>
       </div>

        </div>
        
      </div>
       </div>
                   <!--######
     Login From End
                             #######--->
  
       </div> 
    
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 9999;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" style="padding:5px 50px;">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4>Register</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form method="POST" id="registerForm"  class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="usrname"> Username</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter name">
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="email">Email</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="psw">Password</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="psw"> Mobile</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Mobile Number">
         </div><br>
         
           <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Submit</button>-->
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block" id="register_submit" name="submit" value="INVITE QUOTES">
          </form>
       </div>
       
        </div>
        
      </div>   
     </div>
 </div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: try to create standalone js function (not inside the document ready), called `function register()` and then you can call it via `onclick=register()` event on your button

Comment: What is not working ? I see you have disabled your code in your submit is that why. Does your modal not close ? .. I don't see what you mean with, It is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

DEMO Attached

```js
 $("#submitRegister").on("click", function () {
                var errorCount = 0;
                $("#registerForm input").each(function (idx, li) {
                    if ($(this).val() == "") {
                        errorCount++
                    }

                });
                if (errorCount > 0) {
                    alert("Please fill up the form")
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    $("#registerForm").submit();

            });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">

        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">login</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">register</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="register" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Register </h4>
                    </div>
                    <form method="POST" id="registerForm" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="usrname"> Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="psw">Password</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="psw"> Mobile</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                            </div><br>

                           




                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <button type="button" id="submitRegister" class="btn btn-info btn-block">INVITE QUOTES</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```